# Globalize / Cldr : Globalize.formatDate(new Date(), {datetime:"long"}) resulted in something like "16. januar 2017. 13.30.17 GMT+1"

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, globalize, cldr

I have ASP.NET MVC 5 application, and my Globalization / Validation (Globalize 1.2.2) loads are:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/cldr.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/cldr/event.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/cldr/supplemental.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/globalize.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/globalize/number.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/globalize/date.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.globalize.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $.when(
            $.getJSON("@Url.Content("~/Scripts/cldr/supplemental/likelySubtags.json")"),
            $.getJSON("@Url.Content("~/Scripts/cldr/supplemental/numberingSystems.json")"),
            $.getJSON("@Url.Content("~/Scripts/cldr/supplemental/timeData.json")"),
            $.getJSON("@Url.Content("~/Scripts/cldr/supplemental/weekData.json")"),
            $.getJSON("@Url.Content("~/Scripts/cldr/main/en/numbers.json")"),
            $.getJSON("@Url.Content("~/Scripts/cldr/main/en/ca-gregorian.json")"),
            $.getJSON("@Url.Content("~/Scripts/cldr/main/en/timeZoneNames.json")"),
            $.getJSON("@Url.Content("~/Scripts/cldr/main/sr-Latn/numbers.json")"),
            $.getJSON("@Url.Content("~/Scripts/cldr/main/sr-Latn/ca-gregorian.json")"),
            $.getJSON("@Url.Content("~/Scripts/cldr/main/sr-Latn/timeZoneNames.json")")
    ).then(function () {
        console.log("start slicing");
        return [].slice.apply(arguments, [0]).map(function (result) {
            console.log("slicing done");
            return result[0];
        });
    }).then(Globalize.load).then(function () {
        Globalize.locale('sr-Latn');
    }).then(console.log("LOADED EVERYTHING"));
</script>
```

But now, when I try to test in browser debugger, the command:

Globalize.formatDate(new Date(), {datetime:"long"});

gives unexpected result. Instead colon as time separator, I got a dot: "16. januar 2017. 07.57.17 GMT+1". [JSON repository](https://github.com/unicode-cldr/cldr-dates-full/blob/master/main/sr-Latn/ca-gregorian.json) looks OK in "timeFormats" and "dateTimeFormats" patterns.
Everything is OK with "en", or "de", which has similar time and date patterns defined in repository.

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **dot** isn't a separator, but part of the long datetime format.

The `"16. januar 2017. 07.57.17 GMT+1"` output you get for the long datetime format of `"sr-Latn"` locale is composed of (a) `"16. januar 2017.` long date format, (b) a space separator `" "`, and (c) `"07.57.17 GMT+1"` long time format.

Note [`dateTimeFormats.long = "{1} {0}"`](https://github.com/unicode-cldr/cldr-dates-full/blob/30.0.3/main/sr-Latn/ca-gregorian.json#L325) is what glues date and time (i.e., space separator), [`dateFormats.long = "dd. MMMM y."`](https://github.com/unicode-cldr/cldr-dates-full/blob/30.0.3/main/sr-Latn/ca-gregorian.json#L313) (i.e., there's a **dot** after year), and [`timeFormats.long = "HH:mm:ss z"`](https://github.com/unicode-cldr/cldr-dates-full/blob/30.0.3/main/sr-Latn/ca-gregorian.json#L319)
.

The **dots** used as time separator comes from [`"timeSeparator": "."`](https://github.com/unicode-cldr/cldr-numbers-full/blob/30.0.3/main/sr-Latn/numbers.json#L30).

Having said that, if you believe the **dot** after year is incorrect OR if the separator should be a **comma** instead of **space**, please file a ticket into CLDR: http://unicode.org/cldr/trac/newticket

Comment: The date and space between date and time are correct. Time part is not. Instead dots, separator between hour, minutes and seconds have to be colon (:).

Comment: The time separator comes from https://github.com/unicode-cldr/cldr-numbers-full/blob/30.0.3/main/sr-Latn/numbers.json#L30

Comment: The time separator, resides in "numbers.json!". Logically!!
If you had not given me link to me, I would have never found it! Thnx!

Comment: It didn't seem obvious to me just reading over the formats that `{0}` is the time and `{1}` is the date, especially since it is common to say date-time. However, the documentation clears it up: https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#dateTimeFormat